# Counting dynamically changing elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I an counting the number of elements with span class check_box and uncheck_box with the following code and it work fine. When the item with check-box is clicked, its span change to uncheck-box and vice versa.  I want the count to dynamically change without page reload with the item is click on.

How can i achieve this?

```
jQuery('.complete-count').append(jQuery('.check_box').length);
jQuery('.incomplete-count').append(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
```

HTML:

```
<span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort active showall">All</a></span>
        <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort complete">Completed</a></span>
        <span><a href="javascript:;" class="sort incomplete">Incomplete</a></span>

<ul class="leftlist">
<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
<a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
                <span class="check_box cb"></span>

            <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
</li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
<a href="javascript:;">           
                <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

            <p>Option 1 Incomplete</p> </a>
</li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="1"><a href="javascript:;"> 
<a href="javascript:;" class="strike">           
                <span class="check_box cb"></span>

            <p>Option 1 Complete</p> </a>
 </li>

<li class="todo" id="1011" itemage="2"><a href="javascript:;"> 
<a href="javascript:;">          
                <span class="uncheck_box cb"></span>

            <p>Option 2 InComplete</p> </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you share some markup?

Comment: @David have added some HTMl markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the class of your checkboxes but this should work if there are no more checkboxes:

```
var $checkboxes = jQuery('li.todo a'),
    $completeCount = jQuery('.complete-count'),
    $incompleteCount = jQuery('.incomplete-count');

var updateCount = function(){
    $completeCount.text(jQuery('.check_box').length);
    $incompleteCount.text(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
};

$checkboxes.on('click', updateCount);
updateCount();
```

Basically, we cache the checkboxes into `$checkboxes` and also we store some references to the Complete Count holder and the Incomplete Count one in the same way we did before.

We attach an event handler on the `change` event which basically is the same function you were using before.

Comment: Thanks..this works..but i need to reload the page everytime, the count changes..it does not automatically change.

Comment: also, i am not using check boxes but ahref to make it clickable

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$('.check_box, .uncheck_box').click(function(){
   jQuery('.complete-count').append(jQuery('.check_box').length);
   jQuery('.incomplete-count').append(jQuery('.uncheck_box').length);
})
```